# Using wildcards in names in Windows hosts file

Tags: windows, hosts

Is there a way to create a wildcard domain in the Windows hosts file.

I tried this

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx     *.somedomain.com

This does not work, is there maybe some other syntax I should use?

I am working on Windows 7

Comment: i just answered a question on [doing this with DNSmasq](http://serverfault.com/questions/136332/setting-up-dnsmasq-for-a-local-network/136379#136379) on ServerFault (not on windows, obviously, but on a router running DD-WRT/OpenWRT it's doable)

Comment: XP SP2 included a castration of the  host file -
http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/431032/30/0/threaded

Assumed reason is people were using it to block ads while browsing. This is a guess as far as I know Microsoft has never revealed why they did this and why they are rolling it forward to everything since.

If you are able to put in a proxy server between your PC and the internet, then you could put in a block for what you wanted.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There is not. The hosts file isn't very clever, you have to list every subdomain individually (including www and no-www)

Comment: XP SP1 included an upgrade to a castration of the host file.

Answer (score 24):

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file/4166967#4166967) to a [very similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-hosts-file) worked well for me.

> http://mayakron.altervista.org/support/browse.php?path=Acrylic&name=UserManual
>
> Wildcard Support on XP at hostsfile. Enjoy.

Basically, this program [Acrylic](http://mayakron.altervista.org/support/browse.php?path=Acrylic) works as a DNS proxy for your local machine.  Just point your Local Area Connection to 127.0.0.1, then edit the AcrylicHosts.txt in a very similar manner to the regular hosts file -- only with wildcards!

Comment: Acrylic works great, but can confuse you if you are trying to access a machine with a dynamic IP address. 

I have machines connected to my home network, and I use a dynamic dns to set the ip for the domain name.  I use Acrylic on my laptop and I was gone for a few days, in the mean time my ip changed, but Acrylic remembered it as being the old ip, and I couldn't access the site.  But running the "Purge Acrylic Cache Data" program took care of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately acrylic does not support DNS aliases, which makes it useless to me.

Comment: I checked Acrylic.exe on [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/4c256ab3f30efb9b5fa2aa3a747e990c8a44e6b41375b1fb59006144460da569/detection) and it shows 3 detections: `SecureAge APEX - Malicious`, `eGambit - Unsafe.AI_Score_63%`, `BitDefenderTheta - Gen:NN.ZelphiF.34106.OGW@aOJ8akl`

Comment: @Mikl I'm not defending it, it may be dangerous in it's own right but it is also likely that Acrylic sometimes gets bundled with viruses to redirect users' traffic

Answer (score 13):

[Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is what you need but it doesn't work quite well on Windows.
So I wrote an alternative on Windows called [DNSAgent](https://github.com/stackia/DNSAgent).

You can use regular expression in rules. There is also some advanced features like customizing cache TTL, non-standard-port DNS server, compression pointer mutation, etc. Open sourced under MIT license.

Comment: I know the repository is archived now but I still find this quite useful. Could you explain how does the `rules.cfg` file works?

Answer (score 2):

first, i agree with phoshi that its not possible to do what you want in the hosts-file of windows (neither on unix).

secondly, you have to get control over the result of a request to dns. one option is to use your own dns-resolving on your router (dnsmasq, dnscache+tinydns, bind, whatever, see quack's comment) and tweak it or to use a dns-resolver on windows which you can control as you want.

see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software) for a list of dns-resolvers, check for the "wildcard" column, maybe [powerdns](http://powerdns.com/) or [maradns](http://www.maradns.org/) or [posadis](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/) is something that fits your needs.

Answer (score -4):

It's another syntax:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx somedomain.com

Some examples to explain it:

- 127.0.0.1 .com this line will block all outgoing dnsrequests ending with .com
- 127.0.0.1 somesite.com will block all outgoing dnsrequests ending with somesite.com
- 12.2.3.1 www.dns.com will lead all outgoing dnsrequests ending with www.dns.com to 12.2.3.1

You block/lead all second (third,fourth...) level urls with the top(second,third...) level url in the hosts file.

Comment: Given the last sentence, I assume `www.example.com` is not blocked by the first line, but only when adding `127.0.0.1 example.com`?

Comment: moonfern, I do not agree with your list. 127.0.0.1 somesite.com WILL NOT block all outgoing DNS requests ending with somesite.com, all it will block is http://somesite.com, not www.somesite.com or subdomain.somesite.com or the like.

Comment: That is definitely not the case on Windows, moonfern.