# Blocking *.example.com at the OS (Windows) level

Tags: windows-7, website, blocking

For privacy and performance reasons, I'd like to prevent my computer from ever communicating with certain Internet hosts. I'd like to do this at the OS level, not through web browser plug-ins (not broad enough), or even through my home router (my laptop travels). I'd prefer to use built-in tools.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. I'm all too familiar with the Windows `hosts` file - and its limitations. There seems to be some confusion over whether `hosts` supports wildcards, but my own tests confirm that it does not.

I have experimented with Windows Firewall and the IP Security Policy MMC snap-in. So far as I can tell, both require numeric addresses. I don't want to block specific IP addresses, or ranges of addresses, in part because IP-address-to-hostname mappings can and do change.

Is there any tool in Windows 7 Professional with which I can block (or route to 0.0.0.0) communication with Internet hosts by hostname mask? If not, are there any good, free, third-party tools?

Comment: Wildcard based blocking using hosts is not possible - have a look at [Using wildcards in names in Windows hosts file](http://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file)

Comment: He knows, he's looking for an alternative solution that does support wildcard.

Comment: I was going to say resolv.conf may help, but you're running Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "easiest" way to do this would be to run your own DNS server and add primary zones for the domain(s) you want to block. You wouldn't even need to create 'A' records. any references to hosts within the zone (domain) would be returned unresolved by your DNS server. [Posadis](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/) is one freeware/open source DNS available that runs under Windows (though I have not used is personally). Of course, if you have just about any version of Windows **Server** running anywhere, you can use Microsoft's DNS server.

One side "benefit" of this solution is that you could (if you wanted to) redirect requests to the "banned" domains to an internal "not allowed" web page.

Comment: You sure it's the easiest way?

Comment: Hmm, run my own DNS server. Hadn't thought about that. BIND now runs under Windows and there are a number of ugly but functional web-based GUIs. I bet BIND is every bit as fun to configure as Gentoo Linux is to compile from source. I will have to consider how desperate I am.

Comment: You'll find easy-to-follow instructions in this article: http://alex.charrett.com/bind-on-windows-mainmenu-3

Answer (score 3):

Try an IP blocker

http://blocklistpro.com/download-center/protowall/

There are many other IP blockers available, most allow you to make your own block lists and allow for ip ranges

Some do not work with W7 very well, do your homework.

Comment: I've searched for solutions via Google and not had much luck. That's why I'm here. ProtoWall appears to operate on IP addresses, which is specifically _not_ what I'm looking for. I could achieve the same effect, and probably more ... effectively, via Windows Firewall.

Comment: Not working anymore, 404 error

Answer (score 2):

Taking over the DNS resolver functions is a good solution.  You may want to sign up for an account at OpenDNS and hard code the DNS server settings in Windows to use OpenDNS as your resolver.  They allow you to enter domains that will always be blocked.  Sign up is free but a small fee gets you extra features.

Comment: Kevin M also suggested OpenDNS. I asked him, Will my OpenDNS configuration follow me around from network to network? How does it identify my computer? Via MAC address? Or is there a client I have to install?

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenDNS. They can do category filtering('Nudity', 'Pornography', 'Gambling', 'Adware', etc) in addition to [individual domains](http://www.opendns.com/support/article/39). Downside is that it requires a little extra setup on the server side for dynamic updates, but it is documented [here](http://www.opendns.com/support/dynamic_ip_tech/).

Comment: Will my OpenDNS configuration follow me around from network to network? How does it identify my computer? Via MAC address? Or is there a client I have to install?

Comment: You have to install a client.