# Blocking a url from getting to your computer

Tags: networking

I don't want to allow any connections to the following url - *.akamaitechnologies.com

I have the following in my `/etc/hosts` - `127.0.0.1 *.akamaitechnologies.com`

Even then, I can see network activity from the following - `a23-57-79-64.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com`  and other such similar URLs.

Is there any work around, that no connection between my machine and the urls of pattern - *.akamaitechnologies.com should be made?

Is there anything, that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried using an IP address instead of a domain name.

Comment: It sounds to me like you may need to flush something.  I'd say try rebooting and see if it works then.  Since Akami is a CDN.. I don't think IP would be a valid option; their network is probably spread across quite a few IPs.

Comment: Yep, even after rebooting, I get an Akami. I want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using?

I am asking because according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file) you can not use a wildcard in the host file. if you run windows.  (You will need to specify **every host** which you want to map to 127.0.0.1).

Answers to [the same post](https://superuser.com/questions/135595/using-wildcards-in-names-in-windows-hosts-file) indicate that works on OS/X though.

If you are using an OS which does not allow wildcards in the host file then consider installing your own nameserver on your PC. That way you can let it resolve all queries to *.akamaitechnologies.com to 127.0.0.1 while forwarding all other queries.

As an additional bonus it may even boost performance (at the cost of running an extra program).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. How do I block a url, using a wild card.

Answer (score 0):

M guess is that there is a program or process your are running that calls home for validation.

Run Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.
Right click on Inbound Rules and select new rule.
Select Program.
Click Next and browse to the executable's directory and select it.
Click Next and click Block the connection. 
Click next twice and name the rule and you are finished.

You can also repeat this process for the Outbound rules as well.